# Have I correctly rephrased the sentence?

Tags: grammar

The field of business requires multifaceted practices for real-world problems **as much as** or **more** than any other field.

Revised: ...as much as or more practices than any other fields' practices.

..............

I would like to know if I have correctly rephrased it. In doing so, then, I could get its meaning better.

***Meanwhile***, would you please show me what as much as means here? or rephrase it simple, so that I could get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not rephrase it correctly.

Here, *the field of business* is being compared to *any other field*. The characteristic that is being compared between those two is that they *require multifaceted practices for real-world problems*.

The words *as much as* means *in an equal amount as*, *to the same extent/degree as*. Obviously *more* simply means that the field of business needs it more than any other field.

So, simply put:

- *The field of business* (1) is being compared to *any other field* (2).
- What is being compared is that they both *require multifaceted practices for real-world problems*.
- (1) requires those practices *as much as* (=) or *more* (>) than (2).

I hope this clears your confusion.